# Change <canvas> color using CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, canvas, colors

Is there a way to change the color of the HTML5  element using CSS instead of JS?
I need to customize qTips tooltip pointers using custom LESS CSS rules which I can't refer to using jQuery.

Comment: PS. I tried setting the color, background-color and border declarations for the canvas in CSS but that didn't work, the background color is applied but the element is still showing up on top of it in a different color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I don't know what the issue you are running into but I have a working [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnzS8/)

```
<canvas></canvas>​

canvas {
    background: #cdcdcd;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}​
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems like it should work but I think it's getting over-ridden somehow by the default JS file. I tried applying "!important" to the CSS rules but that didn't do it either.

Comment: Ahh... If the js is rendering to it somehow, you need to change the initialization code so that it grabs the CSS background color and sets it.  I am not sure what exactly the canvas js is doing so I can't help more.